# How can I query multiple select elements that are stored in the db

Tags: php, mysql

Querying of the areas of expertise, which is stored as any array of select items is not working. I'm trying to figure out a way I can get the areas of expertise of the registered farmer when editing.

I have two tables. The register farmer table and the areas of expertise table in the db.

The areas of expertise are stored in the area of expertise table.

The register farmer table has all the data for the farmer registered.

Here is the area of expertise table:

| area_of_expertise_id | id_number_of_the_farmer | areas_of_expertise | register_farmer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23232223 | cultivating | 1 |
| 2 | 23233453 | harvesting | 2 |

Register farmer table:

| register_farmer_id | name_of_the_farmer | age_of_the_farmer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 23 |
| 2 | Mary Doe | 34 |

I want to have a registered farmer id in the areas of expertise table like in the registered farmer table. This will be a foreign key, I guess.

I am trying to query all the areas of expertise for a certain farmer. The queried data will be displayed on their page for editing.

Storing the data in the area of expertise works well. I used a for each loop to store the data. Querying the data is now the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.
May I ask what you have tried so far and what isn't working? While we are happy to help, we are not supposed to do your work for you.

Comment: That said, have you tried: `SELECT * FROM expertise WHERE farmerID = ?`? We don't know the first thing about your structures, so assumptions is all we can make.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I have tried. I wanted to have a foreign key(farmer_id) on the areas of expertise table that is  a primary key on the register farmer table. I have looked up many solutions that none gives me a way to store a primary key of one table in another table and autoincrement as it does on the register farmer table.

Comment: The database has no knowledge of what the data actually means. That's the job of the script.

As such, after calling `INSERT INTO farmerTable VALUES(NULL, "Danny Boy", 55);` you take the insert ID of that call and then use it to populate your expertise table.

To fetch that data, I recommend using two statements, `SELECT * FROM farmerTable WHERE register_farmer_id = ?` and, within the 'fetch'-Loop, call `SELECT * FROM expertise WHERE register_farmer_id = ?` (where ? is the ID of the current farmer.)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to overthink your table design, because this looks like a classic 1:n relationship (and even if it is 1:1, the information does not change)

Try it like this:

```
Farmers:
ID (PRIMARY, AutoIncrement), name, age

Expertises:
farmerID (index), areaOfExpertise
```

Inserting goes as follows (assuming Prepared Statements):

```
INSERT INTO `farmers` VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)`
```

You then retrieve the 'last insert ID' from your active connection and put it into your second table.

```
INSERT INTO `expertise` VALUES (?, ?)
```

To retrieve the information, you go the other way around. To retrieve all farmers, you would use the query

```
SELECT * FROM `farmers`
```

and, to get only a specific farmer (assuming you have the ID) you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM `farmers` WHERE ID = ?
```

Regardless of whether you are looking at all farmers or just one, while evaluating the information, you would access the area(s) of expertise like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `expertise` WHERE farmerID = ?
```

And that's really all there is to it.
Assuming a 1:1 relationship (as in 'Every farmer only has one area of expertise), you could also write it in one go like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `farmers`, `expertise` WHERE ID = ? and farmerID = ID;
```